# How do I turn off sign up for local account link in B2C while using user flows?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have the following requirement that needs to be met but not sure how to achieve it.

Users need to be able to sign in using social identities and also local accounts. I'm not able to use sign in user flow as that causes the user journey to fail when users sign in with social identities for the first time (sign in fails as user obj is not created in Azure AD).

I will need to use the sign up and sign in policy without exposing the sign up link. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using built-in Flows then the only way to "disable" it is to hide that particular element using CSS in your UI template HTML file.

If, on the other hand, you are using custom policies then you can either do it the same way as for built in, or disable the generation of the link by setting the Metadata key setting.showSignupLink to false.

This however works only on specified content definitions:

> Available for content definition DataUri type of unifiedssp, or unifiedssd. Page layout version 1.1.0 and above.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata